# JavaFX WebView Colors Error

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I have a problem using WebView in a project, as you can see in the attached image, the colors shown on the content, I have no idea why and have not found any solution, any ideas?
PS: if you charge the same web in a blank project, works perfectly

[image]

Comment: The question is not clear at all. Please add the html and css file you are using. If possible add an image for the expected output as well.

Comment: the HTML or CSS is no problem, a new project loads the contents correctly, but the project that I have existing content is as in the picture, with colored borders, etc

seems some bug

http://i.imgur.com/uL1mCiF.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebView is in debug mode:

- [RT-23846
  WebView in Debug Mode if logging is enabled](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23846)

A comment on the issue tracker suggests a work-around is to turn off java util logging using the following statement:

```
LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
```